# Running Py ODBC queries?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

Trying to query for dates in an Access DB, and it keeps returning the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/sniederriter/Desktop/SATG.py", line 10, in <module>
        for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.3-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py",   line 1605, in execute
    self.execdirect(query_string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.3-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1631, in execdirect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.3-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 986, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.3-py3.4.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 954, in ctrl_err
    raise ProgrammingError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Date *'.")
```

Here is my code:

```
import pypyodbc

DBfile = (r'C:\Users\sniederriter\Desktop\SATGexpenses.accdb')
conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
cursor = conn.cursor()
print(DBfile)


SQL = 'SELECT Date * FROM 20142015;' 
for row in cursor.execute(SQL): 
    print (row.Date)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: use `SELECT * FROM 20142015` or `SELECT Date FROM 20142015`.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL query is wrong. Following code selects all fields from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

If you want specific fields write:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table
```

But only do one of the things. Either all or specified fields.